# In Spring MVC i cant able to run my server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

`

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)at

java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]at

org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:1

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
```

`

In TOmCAT Server.I can't able to run the project.?

`

SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/SpringMvc4] threw load() exceptionjava.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:118)at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)at

java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)`

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `spring-servlet.xml` is referenced properly in `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```